# Syntax help accessing properties in Generic class and methods

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class `AppGeneralSettings` which I use to Save and Load settings which serializes and deserializes to a file.

I want to intercept the Save and Load methods so I can encrypt/decrypt a password so it's not saved in plaintext. This question is more about accessing any object rather than about encrypting/decrypting or passwords.

I'm having problems with syntax accessing the generic objects to be able to change them. For example the following don't work and give errors

`this.SettingsDict.First().Value.EmailPassword = EncryptPassword(this.SettingsDict.First().Value.EmailPassword);`

`(AppGeneralSettings<T>)this.SettingsDict.First().Value.EmailPassword = EncryptPassword((AppGeneralSettings<T>)this.SettingsDict.First().Value.EmailPassword);`

which give errors

```
'AppGeneralSettings<T>' does not contain a definition for 'SettingsDict' and no accessible extension method 'SettingsDict' accepting a first argument of type 'AppGeneralSettings<T>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How can I access the 'this' and 't' objects in the Save and Load methods to alter the properties before they are serialized and deserialized in these two methods?

Save and Load Method:

```
public void Save(string fileName = DEFAULT_FILENAME)
{
    string filepath = GetFullFilePath(fileName);
    // Encrypt EmailPassword
    //this.SettingsDict.First().Value.EmailPassword = EncryptPassword(this.SettingsDict.First().Value.EmailPassword);
    File.WriteAllText(filepath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this));
}

public static T Load(string fileName = DEFAULT_FILENAME)
{
    string filepath = GetFullFilePath(fileName);

    T t = new T();
    if (File.Exists(filepath))
    {

        t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(File.ReadAllText(filepath));
        // Decrypt EmailPassword
        // t.SettingsDict.First().Value.EmailPassword = DecryptPassword(t.SettingsDict.First().Value.EmailPassword);
    }

    return t;
}
```

Full class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApp
{
    public class GeneralSettings
    {

        public string EmailUsername { get; set; }
        public string EmailPassword { get; set; }
        public int EmailPort { get; set; }
        public string EmailHost { get; set; }
        public bool EmailSSL { get; set; }

    }

    public class UserGeneralSettings : AppGeneralSettings<UserGeneralSettings>
    {
        public Dictionary<string, GeneralSettings> SettingsDict = new Dictionary<string, GeneralSettings>();
    }

    public class AppGeneralSettings<T> where T : new()
    {
        private const string settingFolderPath = @"SomeApp\Data\";
        private const string DEFAULT_FILENAME = "GeneralSettings.jsn";
        private const string cipherPW = "randompw";

        public void Save(string fileName = DEFAULT_FILENAME)
        {
            string filepath = GetFullFilePath(fileName);
            // Encrypt EmailPassword
            //this.SettingsDict.First().Value.EmailPassword = EncryptPassword(this.SettingsDict.First().Value.EmailPassword);
            File.WriteAllText(filepath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this));
        }

        public static T Load(string fileName = DEFAULT_FILENAME)
        {
            string filepath = GetFullFilePath(fileName);

            T t = new T();
            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            {

                t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(File.ReadAllText(filepath));
                // Decrypt EmailPassword
                // t.SettingsDict.First().Value.EmailPassword = DecryptPassword(t.SettingsDict.First().Value.EmailPassword);
            }

            return t;
        }

        private static string GetFullFilePath(string fileName = DEFAULT_FILENAME)
        {
            string dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            string path = Path.Combine(dir, settingFolderPath);
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            return Path.Combine(path, fileName);
        }

        private string EncryptPassword(string plaintext)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plaintext))
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                return StringCipher.Encrypt(plaintext, cipherPW);
            }
        }

        private string DecryptPassword(string encryptedtext)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptedtext))
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                return StringCipher.Decrypt(encryptedtext, cipherPW);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, `T` can be **anything**, from `object`, to `int` to `MyClass`. So unless there is no generic constraint on your class (something like `where T: MyBaseClass`), `T` is just `object` which does not have any `SettingsDict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SettingsDict` is defined in the subclass `UserGeneralSettings`, so you cannot access it from the parent class using `this`.

You also cannot access `SettingsDict` via `T`, as that could refer to any type that has a parameterless constructor.

To be able to access `SettingsDict` you need to constrain `T` to types that contain that property. One way would be to create an interface for all your subclasses such as:

```
public interface IGeneralSettings
{
    Dictionary<string, GeneralSettings> SettingsDict { get; }
}

public class UserGeneralSettings : AppGeneralSettings<UserGeneralSettings>, IGeneralSettings
{
    public Dictionary<string, GeneralSettings> SettingsDict { get; private set; } = new Dictionary<string, GeneralSettings>();
}
```

Then you can constrain your `AppGeneralSettings<T>`:

```
public class AppGeneralSettings<T> where T : IGeneralSettings, new()
```

Which would then allow:

```
t.SettingsDict.First().Value.EmailPassword = DecryptPassword(t.SettingsDict.First().Value.EmailPassword);
```

Comment: Thank you, I still have a lot to learn. Two questions, i) I assume new() has to go last as in `public class AppGeneralSettings<T> where T : IGeneralSettings, new()`?  ii) How do I access T in the Save method when I only have object `this`? Do I need to cast or pass T as a parameter?

Comment: @pathDongle yes, `new()` needs to be last so I've updated my answer. Logically it shouldn't need to be though, because all constraints need to be satisfied. `T` is simply a type, so you need an instance of that type to be able to access `SettingsDict` e.g. `T t = new T(); t.SettingsDict`.